# Firebase multi-path update with childByAutoId possible?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Is it possible to use the multi-path update feature for Firebase in combination with creating child nodes (with auto-id)?
So far I have found only solution for updates where the full path is known only.

e.g.

```
var newData = [String: AnyObject]()
newData["conversations/messages/<placeholder for new id>"] = newMessage
newData["conversations/somethingDifferent"] = additionalData
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Push-ids are generated on the client. `childByAutoId` returns a new `Firebase`, but without sending data over the network.

```
let ref = Firebase(url: "<my-firebase-app>")
let childRef = ref.childByAutoId()

var newData = [String: AnyObject]()
newData["conversations/messages/\(childRef.key)"] = newMessage
```

Once you've created a child reference, you can just use its key in the dictionary for the multi-path update.

Comment: You can pass childbyAutoId a value? What does that do?

Comment: Oh man, my brain. `childByAutoId` is almost like `.push()` in the JS client. I confused the functionality for a second. You can't pass `childByAutoId` a value. The code should still work though.

Comment: Rats. I got really excited - I thought you were revealing a hidden feature.

Comment: Great! Good to know, pretty clever, makes a lot of sense too engineering wise